# Trying to deploy smart contract without truffle (a manual route)

Tags: angular5, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I am a beginner and want to integrate front-end (angular js) with blockchain.

I have successfully compiled and deployed smart contract using Truffle. 
Can I deploy the smart contract without using truffle i.e manual route. 
I have searched many blogs but couldn't find a better source for this question. If you have a better source, please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I have created the plan contract deployer using nodeJS. Please find below code.

Step 1: Install the nodeJS and NPM in your computer.

Step 2: Create "deployer" folder and add package.json in same folder

Step 3: Create "contracts" & "compiled" folder under "deployer" folder

Step 4: created deployer.js file in "deployer" folder.

Step 5: Run $npm install command

Step 6: Keep your smart contract ".sol" file in "contracts" folder.

Step 7: Run $node deployer.js command to deploy contract on local Ganache client (truffle). If you have other client or blockchain node. Please update rpc url in "deployer.js" file. OR install Ganache RPC client, you will find truffle site.

## Files:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "deployer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test deployer",
  "main": "deployer.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Mahesh Patil",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "body-parser": "1.15.2",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "request": "2.79.0",
    "solc": "0.4.8",
    "web3": "0.18.2"
  }
}
```

==========
deployer.js:

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
// Replace the blockchain node url, I am installed Ganache client very easy for testing 
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545/"));
var fs = require('fs');
var solc = require('solc');
var async = require('async');

var cDir = fs.readdirSync("./contracts");
console.log(cDir);
var contracts = cDir.reduce(function (acc, file) {
    acc[file] = fs.readFileSync("./contracts/" + file, { encoding: "utf8" });
    return acc;
}, {});

var output = solc.compile({ sources: contracts }, 1);
if (output.errors) {
    throw output.errors;
};

var owner = web3.eth.coinbase;
web3.eth.defaultAccount = owner;
var contracts = [];
web3.personal.unlockAccount(owner, "", 120000, function (err, success) {
    var all = [];
    Object.keys(output.contracts).forEach(function (name) {
        var contract = output.contracts[name];
        contract.interface = JSON.parse(contract.interface);
        deployContract(contract, name).then(res => {
            console.log(name, " Address: ", res);
        })

    });
});

function deployContract(contract, fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        web3.eth.contract(contract.interface).new({
            data: "0x" + contract.bytecode,
            gas: 900000, // If you get gas issue please change this value according error
            // privateFor: [],
            from: owner,
        }, function (err, myContract) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            if (!err) {
                if (!myContract.address) {
                    console.log(fileName + " : " + myContract.transactionHash); // The hash of the transaction, which deploys the contract
                } else {
                    contract.address = myContract.address;
                    fs.writeFileSync("./compiled/" + fileName + ".json", JSON.stringify(contract, null, 4));
                    //cb(null, myContract.address); // the contract address
                    resolve(myContract.address);
                }

            }
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, you could technically use the Remix online IDE (http://remix.ethereum.org/) if you have Metamask installed.

Comment: Sure. Thank you I will try the way you have suggested